# Proving convergence of series $\sum_{k=1}^n {\sqrt{k^3+1}-\sqrt {k^3-1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove convergence of the following?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {\sqrt{k^3+1}-\sqrt {k^3-1}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: $k$ begin from $1$.

Comment: yes sorry ill change it

Answer (score 1):

hint:$$\sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{k^3+1}-\sqrt {k^3-1})=\\\sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{k^3+1}-\sqrt {k^3-1})\frac{\sqrt{k^3+1}+\sqrt {k^3-1}}{\sqrt{k^3+1}+\sqrt {k^3-1}}
=\\\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{\sqrt{k^3+1}+\sqrt {k^3-1}}\sim \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{2\sqrt{k^3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{k^3+1}-\sqrt {k^3-1}=\frac{(\sqrt{k^3+1}-\sqrt {k^3-1})(\sqrt{k^3+1}+\sqrt {k^3-1})}{(\sqrt{k^3+1}+\sqrt {k^3-1})}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{k^3+1}+\sqrt {k^3-1}}\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{k^3+1}}\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{k^3}}=\frac{2}{k^{1+\frac{1}{2}}}$

Then apply comparison test.